Why does the osculating hyperplane exist?
The problem comes from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, Chapter 4, exercise 4.6. Let $X$ be a complete and nonsingular curve over an algebraically closed field $k$. Suppose $X \subset \Bbb P^n$ and $X$ is not contained in any $\Bbb P^{n-1}$. The genus of $X$ is $g$ and the degree of $X$ is $d$.
Claim: For each point $P \in X$, there is a hyperplane $H$ containing $P$, such that $P$ counts at least $n$ times in the intersection $H \cap X$. $H$ is called the osculating hyperplane at $P$.
If $X$ is a line, then take any $H$ containing $X$ is OK. I do not how to prove this claim for a general curve $X$.

$\renewcommand{\PP}{\mathbb{P}} \renewcommand{\cO}{\mathcal{O}} \renewcommand{\G}{\Gamma}$ We can show that for any $P\in X$, the set of intersection multiplicities of $X$ at $P$ with an arbitrary hyperplane $H\subset\PP^n$ is of cardinality exactly $n+1$ (since $H$ is cut out by some equation $h$, the intersection multiplicity is just the valuation of $h/h_0$ in the local ring $\cO_{X,P}$ for $h_0$ some hyperplane missing $p$).
Take any hyperplane $H_0$ not meeting $P$ and let $h_0$ be an equation for it: then mapping $h\in\G(\PP^n,\cO_{\PP^n}(1))$ to $h/h_0\in \cO_{X,P}$ is an injective map of vector spaces since $X$ is not contained in any hyperplane.
As any two $h$ with different orders of vanishing at $p$ must be linearly independent, we see that the cardinality is at most $n+1$.
On the other hand, if the cardinality of our set is less than $n+1$, then any basis we pick for $\G(\PP^n,\cO_{\PP^n}(1))$ must have two elements $h_1$, $h_2$ which give the same intersection multiplicity $v$ at $P$: this means that $h_1/h_0$ and $h_2/h_0$ are both in $\mathfrak{m}^v\setminus\mathfrak{m}^{v+1}$ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal of $\cO_{X,P}$.
But $\mathfrak{m}^v/\mathfrak{m}^{v+1}$ is a one-dimensional vector space, since $\cO_{X,P}$ is a DVR - so there's a linear combination of $h_1/h_0$ and $h_2/h_0$ with valuation strictly larger than $v$.
Replacing $h_2$ by this linear combination, we see that we can repeat this successively to show that we can always find a basis of $\G(\PP^n,\cO_{\PP^n}(1))$ which has at least $n+1$ different intersection multiplicities at $p$.

Even the set of intersection multiplicities has cardinality exactly $n+1$. I am not sure the set is ${1,2, \dots, n+1}$.

@Functor: the set definitely isn't the one you wrote, since it contains $0$. But it must contain at least one element that is greater than or equal to $n$, which is what is needed for your problem.

@Functor the set is usually $0,1,\cdots,n$, but the cases in which it's not are geometrically special. As Lazzaro Campeotti states, the set always contains a maximum element which is at least $n$, and that's what you need.
